# История изменения стейта | REACT | STATE

Tags: reactjs, state

Можно ли как-то посмотреть и взаимодействовать с исторей изменения стейтов? И есть ли она вообще? Если такой фичи нет, то знаете ли вы, как реализовать такой стейт?

Comment: Выводить стейт в консоль из useEffect/componentDidUpdate ?